# Insert Decimal Point in String After Every Second Number Between Commas

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I need to insert a decimal point after every second number of every string between commas.

**some.file:**

```
JAN,334,333,332,331,330,330,329,328,328,327,327,327
```

**Attempted Code:**

```
sed -i 's/\B[0-9]\{1\}\>/.&/' some.file
```

**Current Output:**

```
JAN,33.4,333,332,331,330,330,329,328,328,327,327,327
```

**Expected Output:**

```
JAN,33.4,33.3,33.2,33.1,33.0,33.0,32.9,32.8,32.8,32.7,32.7,32.7
```

My attempted code appears to be only grabbing (seeing) the numeric string preceding the second comma, not every numeric string in the line, regardless of commas.

Comment: you only missed the `g` flag to replace all occurrences, not just the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$ echo "JAN,334,333,332,331,330,330,329,328,328,327,327,327" |sed -e "s/\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1./g"
JAN,33.4,33.3,33.2,33.1,33.0,33.0,32.9,32.8,32.8,32.7,32.7,32.7
```

For an inplace replacement:

```
sed -i -e "s/\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1./g" some.file
```

No needed here but a *safer* version could be:

```
sed -i -e 's/,\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\)/,\1.\2/g' some.file
```

Comment: this will convert `JAN2017` to `JAN20.17.`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Awk` as below,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if (length($i) >2) { $i=substr($i,0,2)"."substr($i,3,length($i)); } }1' file
```

produces an output as

```
JAN,33.4,33.3,33.2,33.1,33.0,33.0,32.9,32.8,32.8,32.7,32.7,32.7
```

The idea is to loop through element starting from `2nd` record to end the line( upto `$NF`) and apply the logic for numbers having *more than 2 digits*

The [`substr()`](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) is a `POSIX` compatible function, for getting the substring from the current record that is processed.

> *substr(string, start [, length ])*

Return a **length**-character-long substring of **string**, starting at character number **start**. The first character of a string is character number one.

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`, divide all numbers by 10 and print with one decimal point

```
awk -v RS=, '{if($1==$1+0) printf "%.1f,", $1/10; else printf "%s,",$1}' file | 
sed '$s/,$/\n/'

JAN,33.4,33.3,33.2,33.1,33.0,33.0,32.9,32.8,32.8,32.7,32.7,32.7
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk using regex replace:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/[0-9],|[0-9]$/,".&")||1' file
JAN,33.4,33.3,33.2,33.1,33.0,33.0,32.9,32.8,32.8,32.7,32.7,32.7
```

Explained:

- `gsub(/[0-9],|[0-9]$/,".&")` replace all number+commas with period+that number+comma minding the last number in the end of the record
- `||` or
- `1` just print it anyway

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with sed:

```
sed -e "s/\b[0-9][0-9]/&./g"
```